# what are the vulnerabilities of blocking access to files using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security

I am familiar with how to block access to files using htaccess 
and
keeping files outside the document root and serving the protected files through scripts like php.
My concern is what are the possible ways a hacker can use to access files protected by htaccess and the files are inside document root of the web server ?
What are the security concerns here and its remedies?

Comment: bypass http completely. htaccess only applies to apache. sftp, ftp, telnet, ssh, blah blah blah are utterly unaffected by apache-level restrictions.

Comment: could you point out some of the ways or protocols to do this? any links and hints to do this just for learning purpose. there may be thousand of ways to do this? any few of the tricks to research on? thanks

Comment: I just listed a bunch of protocols...

Comment: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/htaccess-security/

Comment: thanks @MarcB. did not realize the stop symbol after apache.